# String compare with 'strange chars' in SqlServer

Tags: sql-server, string, sql-server-2008

I have some content in our database with (for our language) 'strange' characters.

For example:

```
Å
```

When using the `like` statement in Sql Server with the letter `A`, this does not return a result because the `Å` is not an `A`.

Is there a way in SqlServer to treat the `Å` as an `E` (and the `é` as an '`e`' etc)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Do you mean "Å as A" or "Å as E"?

For the first, you can coerce the collation to accent insensitive

```
SELECT 1 WHERE 'Å' = 'A'    --No
SELECT 1 WHERE 'Å' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AI = 'A'   --Yes

SELECT 1 WHERE 'é' = 'e'    --No
SELECT 1 WHERE 'é' COLLATE LATIN1_General_CI_AI = 'e'   --Yes
```

Comment: Thanks, that works.
Have you any idea if this is also possible in Linq to entities?

Comment: didn't find out either, created a SP with your code. Works great.

Answer (score 2):

You can include a [`COLLATE`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms184391.aspx) clause in your query to specify an accent-insensitive collation:

```
SELECT *
FROM your_table
WHERE your_column LIKE 'A%' COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI
```

You'll need to use an appropriate collation for your language. The built-in [`fn_helpcollations`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187963.aspx) function will give you a list of all supported collations:

```
SELECT *
FROM fn_helpcollations()
```